# Classification report in NER models ? seqeval vs sickit learn

Tags: bert-language-model, named-entity-recognition

I'm building a NER model to identify some medical entities. In order to evaluate my model, I used the classification report from seqeval and compared it to sklearn's classification report.

as for seqeval  I'm getting this :

```
print(report)
              precision    recall  f1-score   support

        ENT       0.79      0.84      0.82       578
    abv_ENT       0.89      0.91      0.90       629

   micro avg       0.84      0.88      0.86      1207
   macro avg       0.84      0.87      0.86      1207
weighted avg       0.84      0.88      0.86      1207
```

When I use sklearn's classification report, the results are much better and more detailed

```
print(classification_report(np.concatenate(true_labels), np.concatenate(true_predictions))) 
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

       B-ENT       0.89      0.90      0.89       578
  B-abrv_ENT       0.89      0.91      0.90       629
       I-ENT       0.91      0.92      0.91      1706
           O       0.99      0.99      0.99     22469

    accuracy                           0.98     25382
   macro avg       0.92      0.93      0.92     25382
weighted avg       0.98      0.98      0.98     25382
```

Why is that ? and which one should I trust more ?

Answer (score 1):

The difference relies on what is evaluated:

- seqeval compares reference and system entities,
- sklearn evaluate word labels, including those outside entities.

In brief, NLP people generally only take into account the seqeval metric.

The score difference heavily relies on how "O" labels (Outside, words which are not in any entity) are taken into account by the metric. seqeval will not include "O" labels that are correctly labeled, only those that are wrong, while sklearn will include all "O" labels that are correctly detected as correct positive labels.

Now imagine a dataset containing 90% of "O" labels (10% of words are entities) and a system which does not detect any entity (every word is labeled "O"). The seqeval evaluation will compute a null recall. For  sklearn the recall would be 0.9, considering many "O" have been correctly detected, which is not satisfying as the system did not find any entity at all.